# What's the maximum number of signers for a given account?

Tags: accounts, signer

Submitted externally:

> Can I specify 1000 people can sign on my addr Or is there a limit in
>   terms of the maximum number of signers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, it's 20. This is specified in the XDR for AccountEntry for the size of the signers collection:

```
struct AccountEntry
{
    AccountID accountID;      // master public key for this account
    int64 balance;            // in stroops
    SequenceNumber seqNum;    // last sequence number used for this account
    uint32 numSubEntries;     // number of sub-entries this account has
                              // drives the reserve
    AccountID* inflationDest; // Account to vote for during inflation
    uint32 flags;             // see AccountFlags

    string32 homeDomain; // can be used for reverse federation and memo lookup

    // fields used for signatures
    // thresholds stores unsigned bytes: [weight of master|low|medium|high]
    Thresholds thresholds;

    Signer signers<20>; // possible signers for this account
```

In particular:

> **`Signer signers<20>; // possible signers for this account`**

This is also specified in the docs under the [Set Options operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#set-options) with regard to the `SET_OPTIONS_TOO_MANY_SIGNERS` error:

> `|SET_OPTIONS_TOO_MANY_SIGNERS| -2| 20 is the maximum number of signers an account can have, and adding another signer would exceed that.|`

Comment: There's also the practical limitation of 20 signatures per *transaction*.

You can have an transaction with 100 operations, using 100 source accounts, each with their own 20 signers, and you will still only be able to attach 20 signatures to the whole transaction.